# How to add title rows using Array Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to add title of each column but my formula is populating an error. But when i use this without titles it works fine. But how to add titles using Array Formula.

any help will be appreciated.

```
={"Active","Link","Lake","Temp",Talei","Shmk","Shmtr","Kile";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5:A,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$J,{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},0)))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"Active","Link","Lake","Temp","Talei","Shmk","Shmtr","Kile";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5:A, 'Sheet2'!$A$2:$J, {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 0)))}
```

or:

```
={"Active","Link","Lake","Temp","Talei","Shmk","Shmtr","Kile";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5:A, 'Sheet2'!$A$2:$J, {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 0), 
 {"","","","","","","",""}))}
```